# CB Radio Ground Plane (or lack thereof)

Tags: antenna-theory, mobile

Notice the vertical antenna on the truck. <s>I believe this first antenna is referred to as a "dipole"</s>, mounted vertically. CB to coax, coax to antenna.

The shell of the truck is fiberglass. Even the front bumper is plastic. Of course there is metal; door frames and the frame itself. The shell is also dipped in a rust proofing solution and I had to clean out threads in the truck that the screws go in. So the screws tap into metal instead of the coating from the rust proofing. I also grounded the mounts that I installed on the truck.

[image]

Below, you'll notice the second  antenna I mounted horizontally making what looks like a very skinny and upside down capital "T". It's only mounted there, the second antenna isn't wired to the radio or the first antenna.

**Will this setup work? Will this create the needed reflective element?**

[image]

Comment: Can you post another photo (or drawing) so that we can see where both the existing antenna is, as well as where your proposed second antenna will be, along with its orientation? Also, we don't know what a "Procomm Quad Rod" antenna and its mount look like.

Comment: And how much of this truck is fiberglass, Don? If you **edit your question** and include at many of these details as you are able to, then we likely can re-open your question so that the experts here can help you. :-)

Comment: Procomm makes the best stuff in communications equipment. The Quad Rod is wrapped 4 times with wire to simulate a 102" whip antenna. As far as I  know, nothing beats it. The guys at Procomm tell me a new antenna is coming out that's even better but I have a hard time believing that's possible

Comment: A matching antenna rod going downward and connected to a balun would create a vertical dipole.

Comment: It looks like you're using 3 black-oxide-coated socket head cap screws that thread into the metal frame. I had problems using those because the black oxide coating acted as an insulator, even when tightened. I suggest that you replace those with stainless steel screws and lockwashers.

Comment: I'm in luck. There's a Lowes right by me. I can get those screws replaced tomorrow. hotpaw2 I've read that some place before. Problem is I'm not sure what a "balun" is. I googled it and it says something about, "Providing a balanced output". So where would I find one for CB antennas? And Where would I mount it and the other rod?  I suppose I can just use the extra antenna you see in the second picture. Right?

Comment: Why did you edit your question? You removed 800+ characters, the other photos, and why "blah blah ..."?

Answer (score 2):

as you might guess from it’s name, a dipole consists of two parts, in opposition to each other. A vertical antenna like yours needs an opposing component to act against (usually the earth, or a large plane of metal called a groundplane), and for mobile antennas the ground is usually provided by the metal body of the vehicle. You will notice that the outer part of the coax is connected to the bracket - that would usually connect to the metal body of the vehicle, except that you say your truck is largely fibreglass. This presents us with a few problems, but it’s nothing insurmountable.

If you can get to the inside of the bodywork where the bracket is bolted on the inside, connect some medium-heavy wires to the bolts (they are also connected to the outer of the coax), and run them in a straight line sideways and down in as many directions as you can, for as far as you can. I’d say three wires would be good, four or five better.

These wires will be invisible from the outside, and should help balance the antenna to good effect.

If you have some eyelet connectors [image: like these] then these would be ideal, to allow for a good connection to the antenna.

Comment: Scott Earle, thank you so much! The guys at Procomm said pretty much the same thing. I know it's only citizens band but I paid good money for everything. Plus, I've had a perfectly good radio get fried because I used existing coax on a Freightliner Classic XL that was damaged. Thanks again, it's very much appreciated

Comment: It’s no problem - CB is still radio, the theory is all the same no matter what.

Comment: Why not cut those to 1/4 wavelength? Also, if that mount is grounded to the metal frame, these might not be needed.

Comment: A quarter wavelength is around 8 feet. I think you’d be hard-pressed to go straight for 8 feet in any direction. Agreed that if the mount already bolts directly to the metal frame then it would largely be pointless

Comment: They don't have to be straight. If they are used, they should not be run parallel with the metal frame.

Comment: Yes. Freightliners that are made in Mexico (like mine ) have the body dipped in rust proofing. I had to clean that crap outta the holes where the trucks mount is screwed in. But I've only ran 2 ground wires. One from the trucks mount and one from mine

Comment: The swr is 1.2 across all 40 channels

Comment: @DonHopper **(1)** The wire(s) from the mounting bracket to the truck's frame should be as short as possible. **(2)** A flat SWR like that *could* mean that you have losses somewhere. It does not always correlate with the radiation efficiency.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks again.

Comment: Mike. Yeah, 1/4 wave for the 11 meter band comes to 8'. Lol. The truck is 13' and one would have to get pretty darn crafty to  run a co-phased set up. More so than I believe my employer would be comfortable with. I miss my Classic XL. It had mirror brackets that were perfect for mounting antennas. They even had a complete line of sight. The antennas could "see" each other. It was great until one of the antennas went bad unbeknownst to me. Damaging another radio. Thankfully I know a guy who got it up and running for fairly cheap

Comment: Okay, does anyone know where I can get a balun for a mobile CB antenna?

Comment: Baluns can be obtained at any radio shop, or can be made easily enough with some plastic pipe, some coax and some solder